# Friendly Url MVC4 with ImageResizer

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, httpmodule, friendly-url, imageresizer

I have just installed ImageResizer.Net library to test out resizing feature. I installed it with nuget and after a few seconds it started to run but not the way I like it. I want a neat url rewrite like `/images/{width}/{height}/name.ext` rather than old and ugly querystring like `?width=100&height=200`.

I achieved it by `Application_Start()` and `PipelineConfig.Rewrite` with a regex but was wondering what is the best solution especially concerning speed ?

Answer (score 1):

### The [FriendlyUrls plugin](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/folderresizesyntax) permits this, and can be used as a starting point for developing your own URL syntax. However, we *strongly* discourage this, as the default syntax follows REST principles more closely.

It may be the current fad to eliminate querystrings, but that tends to be a shortsighted mistake in situations where you're applying queries/filters to data (the image), and you have a large query vocabulary. A careful review of REST guidelines will confirm this. Placing image size or other commands into the path adds ambiguity (is it a command or a folder?), prevents easy removal (how do I get just the original image), and dirties the clarity of the URI.

Using a querystring syntax permits easy construction and modification of commands from javascript UIs such as [StudioJS](https://github.com/nathanaeljones/studiojs), and keeps you [RIAPI compliant](http://riapi.org).

Comment: thank you. but what about IIS8 StaticFile Handler and cache ? what is the best syntax for IIS caching ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I put into ApplicationStart :

```
Config.Current.Pipeline.Rewrite += delegate(IHttpModule sender, HttpContext context, IUrlEventArgs ev)
{  
  if (ev.VirtualPath.StartsWith(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/images/"), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
  {
    ev.VirtualPath = Regex.Replace(ev.VirtualPath, @"/images/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)\.(jpg|png)", delegate(Match match)
   {
     string v = match.ToString();
     ev.QueryString["width"] = match.Groups[1].Value;
     ev.QueryString["height"] = match.Groups[2].Value;
     //ev.QueryString["scale"] = "both";

     return string.Format("/images/{0}.{1}", match.Groups[3].Value, match.Groups[4].Value);

   });
   context.RewritePath(ev.VirtualPath);
  }
};
```

And I use 3.3.3 nuget packages below :

```
ImageResizer 
ImageResizer.Mvc 
ImageResizer.MvcWebConfig 
ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.PrettyGifs
ImageResizer.Plugins.SimpleFilters
ImageResizer.WebConfig
```